# Efficient way to copy data from instance of parent class into child class

Tags: c++

I have class scene (from assimp library) and I extended it with some functions and made class sceneChild. Now I need to copy data from instance of scene into sceneChild instance. I know it is possible to write manually something like this: sceneChild.a=scene.a , sceneChild.b=scene.b ... or this.a=scene.a , this.b=scene.b in copy constructor. However something tells me that this can be done in few lines of code. Am I right? If so then how this can be done? Thank you!

I ask about it because I need to perform this copy operation not only with scene class but with many other classes that are full of data and therefore it will take too long to do it manually.

Example:

```
class Parent
{
    public:
        string name;
};

class Child: Parent
{
    public:        
        int age;
};

int main()
{
    Parent p;
    p.name = "some name";
    Child c(p); //  some magic here so that data (in this case string "name") 
    //is copied from p to c so that c.name=="some name"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a code example, it will bee more easy to help you.

Comment: When you want to copy the data? at the creation? At some other point?

Comment: I just want to copy data and when it is done is not as important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not famliar with the scene class, but generaly you can use [initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html) in the constructor to initialize the parent class.

In your example you can use:

```
class Parent
{
    public:
        string name;
};

class Child: public Parent
{
    public:        
        int age;
    Child(Parent& p) : Parent(p) {}
};
```

Comment: Thank you for fast response! I actually tried this approach but compiler was telling me "error: 'std::string Parent::name' is inaccessible" so I was thinking that this approach was wrong. My main look as: int main()
{
    Parent p;
    p.name = "some name";
    Child c(p);
    cout<<c.name;
        return 0;
}

Comment: I found my error: I was missing public between child: and Parent
thank you for help

Comment: @qwertyuuytrewq actually that was my error too, I just fix it :) you're welcome